# solve the differential equation (initial value problem)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I need to solve the initial value problem $xy' + y =x\sin x$, given that $y(\pi/2)=0$.

Any tips on this one? I tried first to solve it by separation of variables but that didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$xy'+y=(xy)'$.  Simply integrate both sides.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: On the left side of the equation, observe that $$xy' + y = \frac{d}{dx}(xy)$$
which is the product rule for differentiation. So we get the equation 
$$\frac{d}{dx}(xy)=x \sin(x)$$
and integrate both sides of it to get
$$xy= \sin(x)-x \cos(x) + C$$
So
$$y= \frac{1}{x}[\sin(x)-x \cos(x) + C]$$